# Shortcuts missing everytime I reboot pc (target on anouther partition)

Tags: partitioning, shortcuts, reboot

Well, I'm new to linux. And I have 2 partitions - one where I have linux installed, and second where I hold my files. I created 2 shortcuts on my desktop, but everytime, when I reboot my pc, they are missing their target. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other partitions first have to be mounted before they can be used normally. This happens automatically when you access the partition with a file browser. There are several ways to mount a partition. I will show you one which only requires normal user rights.

Open Nautilus and go to your other partition. Then press ctrl + L. It will show you the mounting point. You will need this information.

Then open a terminal and enter `df -h`. There will be a line which shows you the mounting point. On the left there will be something like `/dev/sda2`.

Now open "Startup Applications" from the dash. Add one with this command:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /the/mounting/point
```

Comment: lets assume that I want to make a shortcut on "/the/mounting/point" on /dev/sda2

Can I make a startup command to mount "mount /dev/sda2 /the/ "

In order to make future shortcuts e.g on the same partition but on mounting point e.g "/the/2nd_mountingpoint/" without needint to add a new start up command?